# Downloading JAIN SIP

Tags: jain-sip

What is the different between the Jain SIP libraries downloaded from here:

https://mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com/job/JAIN-SIP/

and here:

https://jsip.ci.cloudbees.com/job/jsip/

They are both linked to from the project page here: https://jsip.java.net

Were do I get the latest stable release of Jain SIP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the official location for JAIN-SIP https://jsip.ci.cloudbees.com/job/jsip/

Where did you see a link to the other location?

Comment: Goto: https://jsip.java.net -> Click Downloads on left side menu -> Click the JSIP Download link -> Directs you to https://mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com/job/JAIN-SIP/

Comment: However, even https://jsip.ci.cloudbees.com/job/jsip/ just directs me to a Jenkins CI server. Where do I find the latest stable release?

Comment: OK I see. Thanks. The CI builds are stable and API compatible with each other. Each revision is an improvement. Risky development happens mostly in branches and doesn't affect the CI builds. If you need to keep track of particular revision for other reasons let me know and I can look into it.

Comment: Nope, if you tell me the CI builds are stable that is fine by me. I notice the last several build has failed unit tests. I guess I will use the latest one that passes all unit tests.

Comment: I believe that this was moved to here: https://github.com/usnistgov/jsip

Comment: There was a problem with the cloudbees builds. I am sorting it out. Cloudbees does build from github.com/usnistgov/jsip